# Increasing precision of Octave

Tags: math-software, octave

I notice the values I get from octave are rounded to 5 decimal places. How can I increase that to 6 or 8 for example?

Comment: At the octave command prompt, type `format long`

Comment: Googling "octave precision digits" yielded [this](http://sci4um.com/about6809.html) as the 7th hit, and the one in which the brief "blurb" in Google page suggested a match. I know absolutely **nothing** about octave, so I can't vouch for the answer, but it does lead me to wonder... did *you* try googling?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted by William DeMeo in the comments, the command `format` is what you're looking for. In fact, `format` is common to both Matlab and Octave.

The command is

> `format options` where options are: `short` for 3 significant figures, `long` for 15 significant figures, `long e` (or `E`) and `short e` (or `E`) for using scientific notation ...

More is in manual [here link](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/octave/octave_102.html)

Comment: Link broken. New link is: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Terminal-Output.html

Answer (score 14):

The real answer was never posted to this and I ended up here while trying to find it. The `output_precision` command is what you want. Setting `format long` provides much more than the requested amount of precision. That may be okay, but if you want a specific precision, use `output_precision` instead.

```
>> help output_precision
'output_precision' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/pr-output.cc

 -- VAL = output_precision ()
 -- OLD_VAL = output_precision (NEW_VAL)
 -- output_precision (NEW_VAL, "local")
     Query or set the internal variable that specifies the minimum
     number of significant figures to display for numeric output.

     When called from inside a function with the "local" option, the
     variable is changed locally for the function and any subroutines it
     calls.  The original variable value is restored when exiting the
     function.

     See also: format, fixed_point_format, output_max_field_width.

Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the online version of the manual.  Use the command
'doc <topic>' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
mailing list.
>> output_precision
ans =  15
>> output_precision(7)
>> a = [1 4.4 4.4^2 4.4^3 4.4^4 4.4^5;]
a =
      1.000000      4.400000     19.360000     85.184000    374.809600   1649.162240
>> output_precision(4)
>> a = [1 4.4 4.4^2 4.4^3 4.4^4 4.4^5;]
a =                                                                                                                                                     
      1.0000      4.4000     19.3600     85.1840    374.8096   1649.1622
```